# Can't display an alert using MessageBox in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

In a handler in one of my controllers, I'm running into issues displaying a simple alert message. Using Sencha Touch 2.4.1

`Ext.Msg.alert('Status', 'test');`
--> `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'alert' of undefined"`

As per [these](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?158293-Error-Message-Ext.Msg-is-undefined) instructions, I added the following require statement: `Ext.window.MessageBox` to my controller.
--> `Failed to find any files for /PATH/FILE.js::ClassRequire::Ext.window.MessageBox`

Replaced Msg with MessageBox and removed require statement.
`Ext.MessageBox.alert('Status', 'test')`
--> `"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"`

Ran into the same problem when using `.confirm`.

[Here's](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.MessageBox) the docs - looks like it should work.

Anybody know why it doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to require `Ext.MessageBox` instead of `Ext.window.MessageBox` and had to use `Ext.Msg.alert...` instead of `Ext.MessageBox.alert...` though I'm not totally clear on why.

Saw [this](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.MessageBox) in the docs: "The framework provides a global singleton Ext.Msg for common usage which you should use in most cases."